# What are the # markers in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Why does a # smybol appear when I enter the CSS folder in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: It's CSS file extension icon, like as in the case of a HTML extension file?

Comment: Its just an icon

Comment: what about the `<>` in front of the HTML file, you have no problem with that

Answer (score 1):

It is a **file extension icon**. It **only appears** on files with the file extension of `.css`.